# Scaling a background image / div size when screen size changes?

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my background on my div, I'm trying to get a responsive image scaling on my div when the screen resolution is changed. I currently have it sizing the image down to fit the div but that's putting the image resolution out. I can't seem to get this quite right, so thought best place to ask was here?

Below is an example of how I'm trying to attempt to do this. But I've just grabbed a place holder image for demonstration and set the `.header` height to `640px` as this is where I'm looking for help. If you run the snippet and adjust the window size you can see the issue I'm talking about.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 640px;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/640x360");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.navBar {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="navBar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the background-size to cover or contain (see the difference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)) the image adapts to the size of the div! :)

I have edited the answer, i think now it fits your needs, the image URL is below, so you can compare the result with the image.

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138142660-302e69e74271?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138142660-302e69e74271?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
}

.navBar {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="navBar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the problem I want the image to keep it's resolution and change it's size when the window size is adjusted

Comment: @randymarch sorry i misunderstood, i changed the answer to your expectation

Comment: You can use background-size, for example set width auto and height to be fixed 640px. Eg background-size: auto 640px, and disable repeating     background-repeat: no-repeat; to .header. but on this way there is not the garancy image will go full width.